# How to setup a polymorphic association of People and Users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, models

If there a People model, how can I setup a polymorphic association of Users and Customer?

For example, a Person could act as an User or as a Customer. People could be a User( extra columns: username, password), or it could be a Customer(no extra columns).

I'm trying to set this up so

1. I won't have a separate Users table and Customers table
2. I don't want to have a People table with a lot of empty username and password columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with moo-juice, the correct approach would be people + roles. here's a concrete example:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :roles, :through => :roles_people
  #columns would be username, password, etc
end

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :people, :through > :roles_people
  #a column of role_type would be required here and the values of such would be Customer, User, etc.  in this class you will put logic that is needed to execute the functions of the role
end

class RolesPerson < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :person
   belongs_to :role
   #this is a join model for a many-to-many relationship. you can store info in here about when a person acquired a certain role, etc.
end
```

Comment: so you're saying I should add a Roles table with column role_type; add a role column to People table; and leave a bunch of username and password columns empty for the People table? what does the RolesPerson class do?

Comment: @leonel, the RolesPerson class he suggests, links people to their roles (allowing them to have multiple roles).  Having a load of username/password columns that are empty is no big deal, in my opinion.  In fact, what if down the line you want customers to log in?  You can do this using the suggested model by way of having a "Login" role (also allowing you to deactivate a bad customer!).

Comment: ok. how would i setup the account administrator? if there can only be one account administrator per account and `people belong to account`

Comment: @leonel There would not be any role column in the people table. RolesPerson is needed for the many-to_many relationship between Person and Role - that's its only purpose.

Comment: ideally, the person model would only contain demographic information such as passwords, usernames, etc

Comment: Well I'm setting this up already. But since I have validations for the presence of username and password, now I get a validation error everytime I try to add a person as a client. How would you get around this?

Comment: you can put conditional logic in validations. google rails conditional validation

Answer (score 1):

I would take a single table with empty username/password columns over a separate table.  I would introduce an additional table called `roles` or some such, and another linking table that linked people to what they are (A user, a customer or even perhaps both).

I say this because you don't want two tables and you don't want extra columns.  You have to pick one of them.